# Website loaded into JavaFX Webengine

Tags: javafx, authentication, webview

I want my application to automatically log on the website kolotibablo,but the site does not exist tag form.What should I do to submit? Thanks.

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //
        WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://www.kolotibablo.com/panel/login#login");
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        engine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> observable, Document oldValue, Document newValue) {
                engine.getDocument().getElementById("login").setAttribute("value", "User Name");
                engine.getDocument().getElementById("password").setAttribute("value", "Password");
            //Login
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded in doing this by using the below code. I did not use your `engine.documentPorperty()` listener, so i removed that code altogether.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847951/how-to-click-a-button-on-website-loaded-into-javafx-webengine) I was able to do it with a bit of editing.

```
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
    if ( newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED ) {
        Element login = engine.getDocument().getElementById("login");
        if ( login != null ) {
            login.setAttribute( "Value", "User_Name" );
            System.out.println(login.getAttribute("Value"));
        }
        Element password = engine.getDocument().getElementById( "password" );
        if ( password != null ) {
            password.setAttribute( "Value", "Password" );
            System.out.println(password.getAttribute("Value"));
        }
        HTMLElementImpl loginButton = (HTMLElementImpl) engine.getDocument().getElementById( "login_button" );

        if ( loginButton != null ) {
            loginButton.addEventListener("click", event -> {
                System.out.println("here " + event.getType());
            }, false);
            loginButton.click();
        }
    }
});
```

So this will wait until the worker state is succeeded, and then grab the `login` element, set the attribute, grab the `password` element, set the attribute, grab the `loginButton` as an `HTMLElementImpl`, which allows us to simulate a click on it.

I have left in the print statements so that you can see things were being done as they happened.

Hope this helps.

> Edit 1

So I revisited the problem and I came up with this solution also

```
String username = "User_Name";
String password = "Password";
String enterUserName = "document.getElementById('login').value='" + username + "';";
String enterPw = "document.getElementById('password').value='" + password + "';";;
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
    if ( newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED ) {
        engine.executeScript(enterUserName);
        engine.executeScript(enterPw);
    }
});
```

The only thing I could NOT figure out is how to click on the `login` button. Everything I tried failed. So, I'm sorry about that. But, here is another way to do it also.

Comment: When the download is complete website only passwords can set attribute login.setAttribute("Value", "User_Name");

Comment: it does not install

Comment: `login` must use a different `attribute` then. I won't be able to look until tomorrow

Comment: @KiênĐịnh Edited. For some reason the login button would NOT click or submit, but the username will now be entered as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please use

**HTMLFormElement loginForm = ( HTMLFormElement ) webEngine.getDocument().getElementById("Login");
loginForm.submit();**
To login , you have to submit the Form ,In above code "Login" is form id